# Why npm installs different version of dependency from what is specified in package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, postcss, stylelint

**node -v**
v17.2.0

**npm -v**
8.1.4

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "untitled",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "stylelint": "^14.1.0"
  }
}
```

**npm i**
**npm list postcss**

```
/* Output:
└─┬ stylelint@14.1.0
  ├─┬ postcss-safe-parser@6.0.0
  │ └── postcss@8.4.4 deduped
  └── postcss@8.4.4 (why is here version 8.4.4 ???)
*/
```

Stylelint repository main branch release 14.1.0
package.json postcss dependency:
https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/fcd5ac1ffa4f2ad1f06cb2277aad035ffe309ccc/package.json#L135
is 8.3.11

So, the question is: why npm is installing version 8.4.4 when it should install 8.3.11? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The postcss version in your link is `^8.3.11`. the caret means "compatible with version", and will update you to the most recent minor + patch version. See the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json).

Also, just a note: this is the `package.json` not the `package-lock.json`, which *does* lock you into a specific major.minor.patch version.

Comment: yes, that's right, but for some reason they are not compatible :( thanks, man